Micrometer 1.13.0: Incorrect Metric Name Declaration
I'm encountering an issue with Micrometer 1.13.0 where one of the metric name declarations is outputted incorrectly. Instead of the expected # TYPE jvm_info gauge, it outputs # TYPE jvm info. This metric is a built in metric from spring boot.
This issue is causing prometheus to fail scraping the metrics from my service.
Details:

Micrometer Version: 1.13.0
Prometheus Version: 2.53.0
Spring boot Version: 3.3.0
Metric endpoint Output (before 1.13):

# TYPE jvm_info gauge
# HELP jvm_info JVM version info
jvm_info{application="serviceName",runtime="OpenJDK Runtime Environment",vendor="Eclipse Adoptium",version="17.0.10+7"} 1.0 1719475382493


Metric endpoint Output (after 1.13):

# TYPE jvm info
# HELP jvm JVM version info
jvm_info{application="serviceName",runtime="OpenJDK Runtime Environment",vendor="Eclipse Adoptium",version="17.0.10+7"} 1 1719475509762


Error in Prometheus Server: msg="Append failed" err="invalid metric type \"info\""

This change was noted in the Micrometer 1.13 Migration Guide, however latest prometheus server fails to work with this new name.


Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a known fix or workaround for this?
Thank you!

Prometheus supposed to get metrics in the OpenMetrics format. Quite possible you have issues with headers. See this similar issue

Thanks, i checked the headers and doesnt seem to be the same issue:
from the /metric api i get: content-type: text/plain for both old and new code.

IIUC, content-type: text/plain is ok for old code, because it used text format of metrics. But for new one it should be something like content-type: application/openmetrics-text

Let me address a few things in the comments first; Prometheus supports two formats:

"Prometheus Text format" (text/plain)
OpenMetrics format (application/openmetrics-text)

OpenMetrics is newer and that's what the Prometheus Server prefers but the Prometheus Text format can also be used (as a fallback). Your application should be able to produce both depending on what is asked from it (see content negotiation and Accept HTTP header).
Your application should produce the following behaviors:

If you ask for the OpenMetrics format:

curl -v -H 'Accept: application/openmetrics-text; version=1.0.0' localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus

You should get something like this:
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Content-Type: application/openmetrics-text;version=1.0.0;charset=utf-8

# TYPE jvm info
# HELP jvm JVM version info
jvm_info{runtime="OpenJDK Runtime Environment",vendor="Eclipse Adoptium",version="22.0.1+8"} 1
# EOF

Please notice:

Content-Type: application/openmetrics-text
#EOF in the last line (also indicates that the OpenMetrics format is used)
# TYPE jvm info: this means that the name is jvm and the type is info; info is a type that is only supported by OpenMetrics and not by "Prometheus Text format"


If you ask for the "Prometheus Text format" or you ask for a not-supported format (e.g.: you browser asks for html/xml/etc):

curl -v localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus

You should get something like this:
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Content-Type: text/plain;version=0.0.4;charset=utf-8

# HELP jvm_info JVM version info
# TYPE jvm_info gauge
jvm_info{runtime="OpenJDK Runtime Environment",vendor="Eclipse Adoptium",version="22.0.1+8"} 1

Please notice:

Content-Type: text/plain
No #EOF in the last line
# TYPE jvm_info gauge: this means that the name is jvm_info and the type is gauge; gauge is supported by the "Prometheus Text format"

My guess for your issue is that you created your own Prometheus endpoint instead of using Spring Boot's actuator endpoint and your app does not do content negotiation and returns the wrong format/content-type (e.g.: the format is OpenMetrics but the Prometheus Server thinks it is the "Prometheus Text format").
